# Finding efficiency of an estimator for Poisson random variables

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

$\newcommand{\eff}{\operatorname{eff}}$

I am asked to derive the efficiency of the estimator $\hat{\lambda}_1 = \frac{1}{2}(Y_1+Y_2)$ relative to $\hat{\lambda}_2=\bar{Y}$, where $Y_1,Y_2,\ldots,Y_n$ denotes a random sample of size n from a Poisson distribution with mean $\lambda$.

I know that $\eff(\hat{\theta}_1,\hat{\theta}_2)=\frac{V(\hat{\theta}_2)}{V(\hat{\theta}_1)}$ for two unbiased estimators $\hat{\theta_1}$ and $\hat{\theta_2}$.

So far I have:

$$
\begin{align}
\eff(\hat{\lambda}_1,\hat{\lambda}_2) & =\frac{V(\bar{Y})}{V(\frac{1}{2}(Y_1+Y_2))} \\[8pt]
& =\frac{\lambda/n}{\frac{1}{4}V(Y_1)+\frac{1}{4}V(Y_2)} \\[8pt]
& =\frac{\lambda/n}{\lambda/2} \\[8pt]
& =n/2
\end{align}
$$

Is this correct, or am I missing something? I have to do a short presentation of this problem in class and I'd like to make sure I didn't screw up somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You should have $$\frac{\lambda/n}{\lambda/2} = \frac{2}{n},$$ not $\frac{n}{2}$.  Thus the estimator $\hat \lambda_2 = \bar Y$ is a more efficient estimator (and dominates $\hat \lambda_1$) for all $n > 2$, which makes sense, because $\hat \lambda_1$ discards information about the sample if there are more than two observations.

Comment: Oops! Had that on my paper, but punched it in wrong... Thanks!